# Why does my fully synced Horizon/Stellar Core node return different data from horizon.stellar.org?

Tags: operations

Why does my fully synced Horizon/Stellar Core node return different data from horizon.stellar.org?  I setup my Stellar Core Docker image with CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true and it took days to fully synchronize.  When I query my local fully synced node with the following query:

> curl 'http://localhost:8000/operations?cursor=2388104895795201&limit=1'

I get the following (extra stuff that was identical removed):

> ```
>     "id": "2388229449846785",
>     "paging_token": "2388229449846785",
>     "source_account": "GBK5LIOUSKMAER2MZHZPUPORDOEFGPUEYJBSHCC2SQDQWY4T4IRRN276",
>     "type": "create_account",
>     "type_i": 0,
>     "starting_balance": "100.0000000",
>     "funder": "GBK5LIOUSKMAER2MZHZPUPORDOEFGPUEYJBSHCC2SQDQWY4T4IRRN276",
>     "account": "GALJDUVLEPVARBNMOW3CSKSQO3OGDNF6OSBSKN22T7ERYX3MIYBSZQ3F"
> ```

When I query horizon.stellar.org with:

> curl
>   https://horizon.stellar.org/operations?cursor=2388104895795201&limit=1'

I get:

> ```
>     "id": "2388229449846785",
>     "paging_token": "2388229449846785",
>     "source_account": "GBK5LIOUSKMAER2MZHZPUPORDOEFGPUEYJBSHCC2SQDQWY4T4IRRN276",
>     "type": "create_account",
>     "type_i": 0,
>     "created_at": "2015-11-03T21:51:25Z",
>     "transaction_hash": "dfe88c829651a99f19c0cb2b7934f4e92d43633481d77727e1fa97c737dcdb42",
>     "starting_balance": "100.0000000",
>     "funder": "GBK5LIOUSKMAER2MZHZPUPORDOEFGPUEYJBSHCC2SQDQWY4T4IRRN276",
>     "account": "GALJDUVLEPVARBNMOW3CSKSQO3OGDNF6OSBSKN22T7ERYX3MIYBSZQ3F"
> ```

The difference is that I don't see a transaction_hash or a created_at in my local copy.  This is a minor difference, but I'm working on tools to analyze the blockchain and would like to have the fully history from the beginning of time.
What can I do to get the missing fields?
I assume this has something to do with old protocol revisions, but I don't know enough to guess at a fix.  My only work-around is to hammer the horizon.stellar.org website for my queries, which is not optimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a different version of Horizon server. These fields were added in v0.12.0 which is now a [pre-release](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v0.12.0-testing) but will be released later this week.

Docker image `latest` tag will be updated once this new release is out (or you can use it now by using `testing` tag).